# Get user roles before returning to client ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#

I need to create a controller that will get and delete all users and a certain user, respectively and I've figured out the part to get the users, add them to a list and return the list. But I struggle with the get roles part. Initially I tried a Linq Select and that works just fine (and looks decent) for simply getting the roles but doesn't work for getting the roles for that specific user as well. I've also tried a much worse methods: getting all the users from db in a list, foreach the list and for every iteration in the foreach, create a new object of the type I want to return and assign the role for that user to the respective object property. Doesn't work AND it's ugly.

TL;DR : is this the proper way to get roles in a select and does the 'Role' property need to be IList 100%?

Here's my GetRoles method:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
   var userDbList = _userManager.Users.ToList();

   if (userDbList is null) return BadRequest(AppResources.UsersDoNotExist);

   // my initial select. GetUsersModel is just a model for the object 
   // I return and contains Name, Email, UserName and Role. As you can see,
   // the method is async but I get a cannot implicitly convert System.Collections
   // .Generic.IList<string> to string (I suspect I need to set Role as a List<string>?)
   var userList = userDbList.Select(async user => new GetUsersModel
   {
       Name = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}",
       UserName = user.UserName,
       Email = user.Email,
       Role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)
   });

   /*var userList = new List<GetUsersModel>();

   foreach (var user in userDbList)
   {
       userList.Add(new GetUsersModel
       {
           Name = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}",
           UserName = user.UserName,
           Email = user.Email,
           Role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)
       });
   }*/

   return Ok(userList);
}
```

I have a similar method for deleting a user, only I first check request data and remove the user if everything's ok and then create a list to include in an object (along with a message if the removal was successful) to return.

Comment: I assmue that your `User` object has a `Roles` property. If so, when retrieving the users from the database, you have to `Include()` the roles like so: `_context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).ToList();`

Comment: User is a model that adds to the default IdentityUser: IdentityUser + First/Last Name, things like that and forms a DbSet from the AspNetUsers table. Roles are stored in AspNetRoles table and as such, requires _userManager.GetRoles(user).

Answer (score 0):

When you use async lambda in a select, this return `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`. In you case, the variable `userList` is type of `IEnumerable<Task<GetUsersModel>>`. You need to wait all tasks and get the result like :

```cs
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
    var userDbList = _userManager.Users.ToList();
    if (userDbList is null) return BadRequest(AppResources.UsersDoNotExist);

    IEnumerable<Task<GetUsersModel>> userListTasks = userDbList.Select(async user => new GetUsersModel
    {
        Name = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}",
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Email = user.Email,
        Role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)
    });

    IEnumerable<GetUsersModel> userList = userListTasks.Select(t => t.Result);

    return Ok(userList);
}
```

If the method `UserManager.GetRolesAsync` isn't thread safe, then :

```cs
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
    var userDbList = _userManager.Users.ToList();
    if (userDbList is null) return BadRequest(AppResources.UsersDoNotExist);

    IEnumerable<GetUsersModel> userList = userDbList.Select(user => new GetUsersModel
    {
        Name = $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}",
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Email = user.Email,
        Role = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result
    });

    return Ok(userList);
}
```